Displaying the same styling from a word document to vue
I'm using laravel 9, vue 3 and phpoffice/phpword. I've also uploaded a word document which lives in my storage folder and that word document has stylings in it.
What I'm trying to do is display that word document in my vue page so that you can see it. So far I've only managed for the text to be displayed, but not any of the stylings.
Here is my FileService class
    public function scanDocxFile(File $file)
    {
        $file_path = $file->file_path . '/' . $file->filename;
        $phpWord = IOFactory::load($file_path);
        $htmlWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');

        $htmlContent = '';
        ob_start();
        $htmlWriter->save('php://output');
        $htmlContent = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $htmlContent;
    }

This is my FileController
    public function getFile(File $file)
    {
        $file = fileService()->getSingleFile($file);

        return view('work.single-file', [
            'file' => $file
        ]);

    }

My blade file
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('content')
    <div id="work-app">
        <single-file :file="{{ json_encode($file) }}"></single-file>
    </div>

@endsection

and my vue file
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {{ file }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['file'],
    components: {},
    data(){
        return {}
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {

    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Single File Component mounted.')
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>


Can you not create a PDF and open it in Vue? What the current format of the file?

@kissu - it's a docx format

Not possible to convert it?

@kissu - I want to keep the docx format

Can you open such a format within a regular HTML page (without Vue)?

I can get the words but not the styles
